# Different variation of write-output that could work for this?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to assign a variable to the output that another variable does. I want to pull through all xml files > assign that to a new variable to then be read when I run a script with it. Unsure if that makes sense, I'm bad at wording things sometimes, sorry.

Here's my code, just the bit I'm stuck with currently.

`$var1 = gci .\*location*\* | sort LastWriteTime | where-object { $_.fullname -like *.xml } | write-output $var2`

So basically when I do this the 'write-output' comes through as unable to take pipeline input or the input and it's properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

I was wondering if any of you can help me out and know if there's an alternative to write-output I could pipe into this line of code.

What I am doing is running a Go script that reads xml files through the command line in a custom table to make them easier to read (DMARC Reports) however when I attempt to run the script with just the initial variable it doesn't see the list it makes as a readable format so I thought if I saved it as  'write-output' it might be able to read it.

So when I run the variable I am getting the return of all the files I want listed; but when I run the script it returns with "Error".
Chance are the initial Go script needs tweaking but I just wanted to test it in Powershell first to see if I could work around it.

Comment: It's very unclear what you actually want here. Is `$var1` and `$var2` supposed to have the same values afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, I realised I didn't say what I wanted - I edited it just before I saw this comment - "What I am doing is running a Go script that reads xml files through the command line in a custom table to make them easier to read (DMARC Reports) however when I attempt to run the script with just the initial variable it doesn't see the list it makes as a readable format so I thought if I saved it as 'write-output' it might be able to read it."

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to post some code then... I'm not seeing any Go :)

Comment: Yep - Issue I believe is just in the Go, it's set to only pull through one file at a time by directly pointing to one file instead of all files in a folder. It was just a GitHub repo but I guess I can try tweak it to work for how I need it to. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Again: please post the actual code you need help with, along with a description of _what behavior you're actually looking for_. You still haven't specified what `$var1` and `$var2` should be

Answer (score 2):

*Most* of the time, `Write-Output` will take piped data **or** a variable and dump it into the Terminal for you to Read. This behaviour can change sometimes, especially inside functions or a pipeline. In your case, at the end you have this section:
`... | write-output $var2`. Here, you're telling Write-Output to do two things at once, dump the piped output *and* dump the variable, $var2. Which is where it's getting confused and giving you that error `Write-Output: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`.

Your script is a bit confusing in the format you've provided so let's break it down a bit:

Like you've said, gci exports a bunch of XML files, without knowing exactly what that looks like I can only speculate on how to format the data but here's an example:

```
# Save the output of gci into the $XMLData variable
$XMLData = gci .\*location*\*

# Pipe $XMLData into your selector and formatter
$FormattedXML = $XMLData | sort LastWriteTime | where-object { $_.fullname -like '*.xml' }

# Finally, output your data to the terminal
Write-Output $FormattedXML
```

If you wanted to do it all in one line still you could do this:

```
gci .\*location*\* | sort LastWriteTime | where-object { $_.fullname -like '*.xml' }
```

There is no need to save the data to a variable or pipe it into Write-Output, it will go to the terminal by default. However, if you did want to save it to a variable, you could write it like this:

```
$var1 = gci .\*location*\* | sort LastWriteTime | where-object { $_.fullname -like '*.xml' }
```

Variable declarations always go at the start and store the data that proceeds them, Write-Output isn't used to pipe data into variables, which I think is where the confusion started here.

`Write-Output` can be thought of as taking data from the left and sending it to the right, if there's nothing to the right, it will send it to the terminal. This example breaks down a bit, because any object immediately proceeding Write-Output (on the right) counts as a parameter and becomes the input object, any pipe after that though would then be the output. Write-Output is rarely necessary, because most objects send data to the pipeline by default, for example:

```
$animals = @("cat", "dog", "cow")

# Prints $animals contents to the terminal.
Write-Output -InputObject $animals

# But this is functionally equivalent to
$animals

# Stating a variable on it's own is sent to the pipeline, which on it's own will go to the terminal.

# Pipes $animals into Sort-Object then prints to the terminal
Write-Output -InputObject $animals | Sort-Object | Write-Output

# But you could also just do
$animals | Sort-Object
```

However, while stating a variable on it's own *will* print it to the terminal, this isn't always good for readability, so it can be useful to explicitly use Write-Output when you are creating messages in your code.

The [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.3#description) for `Write-Output` explains more.

Comment: +1, but small nitpick - "Write-Output will take data from the left and send it to the right" isn't strictly true - contrived counterexample ```$x = write-output 100```. What it does is take an input object (or objects) from the ```-InputObject``` parameter or from the pipeline and writes them to the success stream.

Comment: @mclayton Thanks I've tried to clarify that part to prevent any confusion.